# Why is the length different?

Tags: tstringlist

`//delphi 7 procedure TForm1.Button1Click(Sender: TObject); Var strList: TStringList; strLength: String; begin strList:= TStringList.Create; strList.Text:= 'example'; // 7 characters  strLength:= IntToStr(Length(strList.Text)); Showmessage(strLength); //  9 characters strList.Free; end;`
strList.Text:= 'example'; where the length is 7 characters
Showmessage(strLength); why am i getting the 9 character result?

```
Thank you in advance to those who are interested.
```

Comment: Why is there a problem while adding the program code?

Comment: TStringList add 2 characters at the end of string. Its symbol #13 - "Carriage return" and synsol #10 - "Line feed". That's why you get +2 symbol to length of string

Comment: If you use modern version of Delphi - you can set property `strList.TrailingLineBreak := false;` to prevent this behaviour.